# fscanf() fails to read

Tags: c, scanf

```
    int ingatlanazonosito, alapterulet, emelet, szobak_szama, rezsi, berleti_dij;
    double x, y;
    char cim[300], butorozott[13];

    while (fscanf(ingatlanfile,"%d;%[^;];%lf;%lf;%d;%d;%d;%[^;];%d;%d\n",
            &ingatlanazonosito, cim, &x, &y, &alapterulet, &emelet,
            &szobak_szama, butorozott, &rezsi, &berleti_dij) != EOF)
    {
        ingatlanbeszur(&ingatlanok, ingatlanazonosito, cim, x, y,
            alapterulet, emelet, szobak_szama, butorozott, rezsi,
            berleti_dij);
    }
```

I have a problem with the code listed above, the problem is `fscanf` fails to read the second string (`%[^;]`) and everything after it. I open the files correctly and everything before the second string is correct. The `butorozott` string is full of \0 s.
This is in the `ingatlanfile` text file:

```
123456;Irinyi Jozsef u.;47.473;19.053;18;15;butorozott;1000;9500
```

How should I solve this?

Comment: "butorozott;1000;9500" is invalid for `"%d"` conversion. `scanf()` returns `6` (**not the expected `10`**) which is not `EOF`. Rather than testing for "not EOF", test for the expected assignments: `while (scanf(...) == 10) { /*whatever*/ }`

Comment: To make your code a [mcve], you should add a `main()` and `#include <stdio.h>`.  You should also switch to `sscanf()` so that the program is self-contained, without losing the character of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input line does not contain 3 integers after the first string, so `fscanf` fails to convert the 7th field and returns `6` instead of the expected `10` fields.

Using `fscanf` to parse input is error prone and does not allow for proper error detection and recovery. You should instead use `fgets()` to read input one full line at a time, and use `sscanf()` to attempt the conversion, producing an informative error message in case of failure.  Also make sure you prevent buffer overflows by telling `scanf()` the maximum number of characters to store into the destination arrays for `%[` and `%s` conversions.

```
    char buf[500];
    int ingatlanazonosito, alapterulet, emelet, szobak_szama, rezsi, berleti_dij;
    double x, y;
    char cim[300], butorozott[13];

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, ingatlanfile)) {
        int n = sscanf(buf, "%d;%299[^;];%lf;%lf;%d;%d;%d;%12[^;];%d;%d\n",
                       &ingatlanazonosito, cim, &x, &y, &alapterulet,
                       &emelet, &szobak_szama, butorozott,
                       &rezsi, &berleti_dij);
        if (n != 10) {
            fprintf(stderr, "conversion error for field %d: %s\n", n + 1, buf);
             continue;  // or some other error recovery decision
        }
        ingatlanbeszur(&ingatlanok, ingatlanazonosito, cim, x, y,
                       alapterulet, emelet, szobak_szama, butorozott,
                       rezsi, berleti_dij);
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Thaks for your answer, now it works how it supposed to work. Have a great day!

Comment: We shall see if he circles back or if this is a classic *Grab-n-Go* that leaves the answer unaccepted :(

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i accepted it ;)

Comment: @PéterUjhelyi - thank you, and good job. You wouldn't believe the number of valid answers left unselected that float around in the unanswered queue forever...